# .htaccess, WordPress and mod_speling

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, case-insensitive, mod-speling

I've got a server that has in its root directory a bunch of subdirectories, one of which has a WordPress.

```
directory1
directory2
wordpress
directory3
```

All of these except for the WordPress were migrated from a Windows server to a Linux server which means that we've lost case insensitivity.

I want the WordPress to be able to serve a URL like `http://www.example.com/~subdomain`, so there's an index file in the root directory. I also have two .htaccess files, one in the WordPress and one in the root directory.

The following is the root directory's .htaccess. 
This is where I'd like to put mod_speling's case insensitivity directives, but it conflicts with the rewrite rule.

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /~subdomain/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /~subdomain/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Below is the WordPress subdirectory's .htaccess

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /~subdomain/wordpress/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /~subdomain/wordpress/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

I've tried using a symlink in the root directory to point to the WordPress directory's index.php. I set the symlink to be the DirectoryIndex but unfortunately it results in a lot of the links turning into 404s.

At this point I'm kind of stuck. Any ideas?

Comment: how's your folders look like? server/wordpress ?

Comment: Pretty much as they do above. There's a root directory with several subdirectories, one of which is wordpress.

It looks like
`dIrectory1
direcTory2
diRectory3
wordpress`

The crux of the issue is that all of these directories have links elsewhere on the web and the casing isn't standardized. Standardizing the casing on the server unfortunately doesn't get my anywhere because of the myriad links out there (too many from almost 10+ years).